# How to make CLI applications in Unix?

Tags: command-line, vim, programming

How are apps like vim and w3m built? I was trying to find info about this online but I couldn’t really find much.

Comment: "_How_" as in what language, or what design process and architecture, or what development environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the project's source code repositories. For instance, the vim source code can be found at: https://github.com/vim/vim

However, you probably want to start a few steps earlier, as such large and grown projects tend to be very complicated.

But I don't think this was your intended question. I assume you are rather interested in how to create terminal UIs. Behind the scenes this is basically writing a bunch of magic characters with `printf` which make the terminal do stuff like switching to alternative buffers or printing in different colors. There is even [a Wikipedia page on the codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). But normally you would use a library that is abstracting away the low level parts like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).
For more details, you could for instance check [this article](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/12/04/how-less-works/) which looks like it answers your actual question.